# Ubuntu 18 was working. Now boots to blank screen

Tags: boot, login, lightdm

I had my Gigabyte Aero 15 (I had previously the nvidia 390 installed) working fine with Ubuntu 18.04. I allowed some updates to install, and then I had problems booting past the login screen. I tried a few suggestions about booting into wayland, and then switching between gdm3 and lightdm, but now I'm stuck - the machine after boot cannot get me to the login prompt, and all I get is a blank/black screen with a small non-blinking curser in the upper left. I've tried adding nomodeset to grub, and the system runs through a lot of boot lines which go quickly so I can't read them, and then still it ends up with a blank/black screen and the cursor in the upper left. I'd like to avoid having to reinstall and lose everything on the machine. Ideas on what to try?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94419/discussion-on-question-by-jan-ubuntu-18-was-working-now-boots-to-blank-screen).